# Javascript mousemove event listener is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dom-events

I am trying to make a particular `<p>` element remain visible, only when my mouse is within the `<iframe>` element and moving within the `<iframe>` element. If the mouse is outside the `<iframe>` element or is stationary within the `<iframe>` element, then it should hide the `<p>` element.

I am using the `mousemove` event listener, which after having looked at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove, which defines the `mousemove` event as **"The `mousemove` event is fired when a pointing device (usually a mouse) is moved while over an element."**.

However if you test the code on the HTML snippet, this does not seem to be the case for me, because once my mouse moves within the `<iframe>` element it does make the `<p>`element, however it still disappears after some time the timeout triggers and hides it. Moving the mouse within the iframe element, does not seem to trigger the `mousemove` event again until you move the mouse outside of the `iframe` window and then move it back in again.

Also the `mousemove` event is not always being triggered when i move the mouse from outside the `<iframe>` element to inside the element.

Can somebody please explain to me why the `mousemove` event is not being triggered again when the mouse is moved within the `<iframe>` element and also show me how I can achieve my `<p>` element to only appear when the mouse is within the `<iframe>` element and is moving inside the element.

Have i misunderstood the definition described for the `mousemove` event from mozilla's documentation, found on the link above? because based on my understanding its implying that the `mousemove` event will be triggered when the mouse moves within the element.

Thank you very much and Merry Christmas.

```js
function showP() {
  document.getElementById('p').classList.remove('hide');
}

function hideP() {
  document.getElementById('p').classList.add('hide');
}

var timer;

document.getElementsByClassName('iframe')[0].addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
  console.log('Entered iframe');
  clearTimeout(timer);
  showP();
  timer = setTimeout(hideP, 3000);
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<iframe class="iframe" src="https://test.com/" width="100px" height="100px">

</iframe>

<p id="p" class="hide">
  Showing P Tag
</p>
```

Comment: Have you tried onmouseover and onmouseout? When onmouseover is triggered for the iframe, then you showP and when onmouseout is triggered for the iframe, you hideP.

Comment: @vlam i tried both `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`, however they only trigger when you move into the element from outside, or vice versa for `onnmouseout`, and dont work when you move the mouse within the element. Currently it seems like the `mousemove` event is behaving exactly the same way as  `onmouseover`, which is it is triggered only once when you move the mouse from outside the `iframe` to inside it. But it doesnt solve my other issue, which is to have it re-trigger when mouse is moving inside the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iframes can be tricky. You can try to wrap the iframe in a div, and target that div in your JS instead:

```
<div class="iframe" width="100px" height="100px">
   <iframe src="https://test.com/" width="100px" height="100px">
   </iframe>
</div>
```

I'm pretty sure this way you can also use onmouseover and onmouseout, or any other event. You may need to add CSS:

```
iframe {
pointer-events: none;
}
```

see working codepen: https://codepen.io/geochanto/pen/wRqvqo

Comment: Just tried it, but unfortunately after placing it within a div, the event no longer seems to even want to trigger. See: https://jsfiddle.net/jewyLqum/1/.

Comment: ok, you need one more thing, add CSS pointer-events: none; for your <iframe> . Then it works. Check it out: https://codepen.io/geochanto/pen/wRqvqo

Comment: It wasn't workiing because your <iframe> was still overlaying the <div class="iframe"> so your mousemove event was not being detected. Another way to do this would be to absolute-position the div OVER the iframe.

Comment: Thankyou, setting `pointer-events: none`, helps make it work, but now unfortunately because of this, the site I have loaded on my Iframe, is unable to detect any of its click events. I found the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990536/how-to-pass-click-events-from-one-div-to-another, which I can use to detect a click even on the container div, and then, hopefully if it works, pass the event to the iframe, however this may still not be accurate as I can't define for the iframe which mouse position the click event was triggered. Do you have a solution around this? Thanks.

Comment: then you can play with pointer-events and enable/disable it when you need. I modified it with jQuery here: https://codepen.io/geochanto/pen/LMjVaB

This will allow clicking, but only after mousemove. If it times out, mouse needs to move before you can click. Anyway, there's many ways to do this. Based on what you've asked this works. If you need something more, then please provide full description of what you're trying to achieve or we'll be going back and forth for too long ;)

Comment: Thats ok mate, thank you very much, you have definitely answered my question and helped me solve my issue. To give you a context of what I was trying to achieve from this, is basically something you will see when you watch any YouTube video on desktop mode. When you move your mouse over the video the controls appear and if you stop moving the mouse, or move it outside of the video player then the controls disappear after a while, and I wanted to make an overlay like similar to this to switch between a bunch of iframe sources :), but without disrupting the iframe sources mouse events.