# How to pass or bubble a click event to another layer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project which I need to edit and do some actions with elements. I have some DIVs as elements inside a group DIV and another DIV overlay them. My problem is that when I click on overlay and do some actions I want any element below overlay also be clicked.

I tried bubbling but since overlay element is not in the same div it does not work for me. I also tried manually trigger the event but since I don't know which element is below where it's been clicked, cant get expected result.
I also found this article [How to pass click events from one div to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990536/how-to-pass-click-events-from-one-div-to-another) similar to my problem but not exactly because I also need to do some actions with overlay layer on click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#group').on('mousedown', function(evt) {
    // Do some action
    console.log('group');
  });
  $('#overlay').on('mousedown', function(evt) {
    // Do some action
    console.log('cover');
  });
  $('.item').on('mousedown', function(evt) {
    // Do some action
    console.log('item-' + $(this).html());
    evt.stopPropagation()
  });
});
```

```css
#group {
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #eee;
}

#overlay {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 left: 50px;
 width: 250px;
 height: 250px;
 background-color: #000;
 opacity: 0.2;
 z-index: 10;
}

.item {
 position: absolute;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 font-size: 4rem;
 line-height: 140px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="group">
 <div class="item" style="top: 60px; left: 60px; background-color: #fcc;">A</div>
 <div class="item" style="top: 170px; left: 170px; background-color: #cfc;">B</div>
</div>
```

**I want to when I click on overlay, if any 'item' div exist below overlay also be clicked.**
I used jquery but can accept any solution with raw JavaScript.

Comment: What's the point of the overlay then?

Comment: I use it to move, rotate or scale the group of items.

Comment: you could probably just implement a collision detector witch when a square is clicked will check the collision detector and it would return and array of all the elements which are being in collision with.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNV-xEMALr8

Comment: I also tried collision but problem is sometimes items have rotation and collision checks .getBoundingClientRect and it contains an area which is not part of that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer with `document.elementFromPoint` which works fine and all modern browsers support.
When overlay div has been clicked, I hide Overlay and check which element is under overlay on mouse event position.
I used `MouseEvent.clientX` , `MouseEvent.clientY` with `document.elementFromPoint` to determine the element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#group').on('click', function(evt){
  console.log('group');
 });
 $('#overlay').on('click', function(evt){
  console.log('cover');
  $(this).css('display', 'none');
  var element = document.elementFromPoint(evt.clientX, evt.clientY);
  $(this).css('display', 'block');
  $(element).trigger('click');
 });
 $('.item').on('click', function(evt){
  console.log('item-' + $(this).html());
  evt.stopPropagation()
 });
});
```

```css
#group {
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #eee;
}

#overlay {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 left: 50px;
 width: 250px;
 height: 250px;
 background-color: #000;
 opacity: 0.2;
 z-index: 10;
}

.item {
 position: absolute;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 font-size: 4rem;
 line-height: 140px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="group">
 <div class="item" style="top: 60px; left: 60px; background-color: #fcc;">A</div>
 <div class="item" style="top: 170px; left: 170px; background-color: #cfc; transform: rotateZ(45deg);">B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Woof, that's creative, but super hacky. Seems like it would make your overlay flash.

Comment: Instead of changing the "display" style between "block" and "none", toggling the "pointer-events" between "auto" and "none" should also have the same effect (without having the overlay flash problem @frodo2975 mentioned ). I haven't tested this yet (will test and update the comment), however the "elementFromPoint" documentation suggests this should work (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint )

Comment: The above comment suggesting changing "pointer-events" doesn't seem to work when tested. The "elementFromPoint" documentation suggests this should work, though, as the function should ignore elements with pointer-events set to "none" as per (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint ). Not sure why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do sounds like an anti-pattern. The browser isn't designed to apply the same click to multiple items. Instead, you should ask yourself why you need the same event handled on multiple elements, and redesign your UI and business logic in a different way so that that's not necessary. Like, you have a common method that gets called on click, and you make your under-layer and your over-layer both call that same method.

That being said, if you really need something like this, like for a game with multiple items under the cursor, you would need to implement manual hit detection instead of relying on the browser. Like, you listen for mousedown+mouseup events on a big parent container, you get the coordinates of all your clickable things using $().offset(), and you do math to see if the mouse coordinates are over your clickable things.

Comment: Till now its the only solution I found but I have problem with Items that have rotation which makes the math calculation so difficult or maybe impossible.

Comment: Nothing in math is impossible. Some things just take more work than others. Why do you need the click event on both the objects and the overlay?

Comment: It's a group of elements with an overlay which control the group with actions like move, scale or rotate. So mainly my actions happens on overlay but I also need to know which element of group clicked or selected.

Comment: Since it sounds like the buttons in your overlay are already positioned over a specific object, it sounds like you should already know which element is being clicked.